# C++ application fails - no errors

Tags: c++

I have started to learn C++ and this is causing me a headache. I have written a simple person "database" application and for some reason it fails when listing persons.

```
string search;
cout << "Give the name: ";
cin >> search;

vector<Person> foundPersons;
for(vector<Person>::iterator it = persons.begin(); it != persons.end(); it++) {
    Person p = *it;

    if(search == p.getFirstname() || search == p.getSurname()) {
        foundPersons.push_back(p);
    }
}

if(!foundPersons.empty()) {
    cout << "Found " << foundPersons.size() << " person(s).\n\n";
    cout << "Firstname\tSurname\t\tBirth year\n";
} else {
    cout << "No matches.";
}

for(vector<Person>::iterator it = foundPersons.begin(); it != persons.end(); it++) {
    Person p = *it;
    cout << p.getFirstname() << "\t\t" << p.getSurname() << "\t" << p.getBirthYear() << "\n";
}

cout << "\n";
```

`persons` is type of `vector<Person>`. I go through all the entries and compare the name against the given search value. If found, I add the person in the `foundPersons` vector. Then I print either `No matches` or the number of found persons and the table header. Next I will go through all the found persons and print them in to the console.

If I add two persons, eg "Jack Example" and "John Example" and I search for "Jack", it will find the "Jack" and print it. But then the program stops. Windows says "The program has stopped working". No errors are shown during the compile or when the program stops.

What's wrong?

Comment: There's always a reason.

Comment: How is `Person` defined?

Comment: I suggest you run the program through a debugger - that should at least indicate where the program stops.

Comment: Of course there's a reason for it not to work. It just doesn't show up anywhere...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're for loop isn't quite right, it looks like you've made a typo and are referencing iterators from two different lists.  Change:

```
for(vector<Person>::iterator it = foundPersons.begin(); it != persons.end(); it++) {
```

to

```
for(vector<Person>::iterator it = foundPersons.begin(); it != foundPersons.end(); it++) {
```

Comment: +1 for amazing eyes :)

Comment: the same error is also in the first `for` loop.

Comment: @Bill his first loop looks ok to me.  I've referenced the incorrect loop in my answer to show where the error is.

Comment: I know that..I dnt see any `vector` for `persons`, so not sure if that is intentional or a typo. This is the only vector defined in code `vector<Person> foundPersons;` ...may be the code does not show that.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Good and fast.